# VBA code to ignore if Target cell is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to trigger a code If target is following:

```
If Target.IndentLevel = 0 And Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone _
And IsEmpty(Target) = FALSE??? And Target.Cells.Count = 1
```

IsEmpty doesn't look right. How to ignore if target(cell) is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since one of your conditions tests `Target.Cells.Count = 1` When this is False  (Target has > 1 cells) some of other tests will throw errors.  Layer your If's instead

```
If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
        If Target.IndentLevel = 0 Then
            If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
                 ' your code
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
```